# A true no-no-gram

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, nonogram

This is a [nonogram](/tags/nonogram/info) with the usual rules. That is, you must fill white squares in with black so that the numbers at the head of each row or column indicate, in order, the respective lengths of sequences of black squares in that row or column.

…except that I've committed a [no-no](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-no).  There are four ambiguous squares in the diagram: seemingly, either a specific two of them or the other two can be colored black.  Normally that means the nonogram is unsolvable.  In this case, though, you'll find that only one of those possibilities yields a valid solution.

[image]

Comment: [making-of](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56168195#56168195)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the grid as far as it solves (with absolutely basic solving techniques only, there are several "full" rows and columns, so you can only get stuck if you make a mistake):

> [image]

Obviously, the remainder is supposed to be solved by

> scanning the QR code,

but since OP foiled any plans of creating a clean image by using dotted lines that don't stop the paint bucket tool, it'll take a moment to transfer the result into some more suitable format that

> can be read by a QR code app.

Here's the cleaned-up picture of the variation that scans. It leads to [some kind of rabbit hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRvMq.jpg), it seems.

> [image]

It's way past my bedtime, so I won't be delving any deeper today.

Here's the discovered image with some (hopefully helpful) annotations:

> [image]

although there might be a simpler way to group them:

> there are 4 white-green flags, 4 red-white flags, 4 blue-white flags, and 4 flags with approximately seventy-two colours each.

Comment: Note that rot13(bar havg bs juvgr fcnpr nebhaq gur ragver vzntr vf nyfb n cneg bs DE pbqr. Zbfg, vs abg nyy, fpnaaref jba'g erpbtavmr vg bgurejvfr!)

Comment: Sorry about the dotted lines! I did it because they looked good and didn't think about the effect on the bucket tool.

Comment: Not just 72, the same 72.  (Actually, only six -- but the same six.)